# Is there a way to update the version in package.json (npm version minor) in maven's pom.xml file?

Tags: maven, npm, npm-scripts

I would like to update the version in package.json automatically when running a maven release. How do I update the version (npm version minor) in the pom.xml file ?

I've tried updating the pom.xml file with a plugin

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${maven.release.plugin.version}</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>npm run version</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <configurations>
        <executable>cd</executable>
        <arguments>
          <argument>web/gui</argument>
        </arguments>
        <executable>npm</executable>
        <arguments>
          <argument>run</argument>
          <argument>version</argument>
        </arguments>
      </configurations>
    </execution>
  <executions>
</plugin>
```

Nothing really happened when I ran mvn clean:release

Comment: Yes, there's an option based on this package https://github.com/MashupMill/sync-pom-version-to-package